# How to add a folder to a path before the filename?

Tags: rust, path, filepath

How do I change "C:\foo\bar.txt" to "C:\foo\baz\bar.txt" using either `Path` or `PathBuf`?

I want to add a folder to the path immediately before the filename.

Comment: It is a string operation. Use the [std::str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/index.html) module

Comment: I don't believe treating paths as strings is cross-platform.

Comment: you are right, but paths are not cross-platform, different on Linux and on Windows. AFAIK, the backslash character \ on Windows is separating directories. On Linux or MacOSX, you'll use the forwardslash `/` for a similar purpose.

Comment: `Path` and `PathBuf` appear to be cross-platform: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/index.html `These types ... work directly on strings according to the local platform's path syntax.`

Comment: I heard that on Windows you have a notion of drive: `C:\foo\bar` is different of `D:\foo\bar`. There is no equivalent on Linux (just mount points). So in my opinion file paths are genuinely different on Windows and on Linux. I admit that I am coding since 1974 but never used Windows

Comment: I don't know how to make an example that makes sense for both platforms if taken literally.  What I want is to add a folder to the path immediately before the filename.  @BasileStarynkevitch Today is the first day I have used Linux, haha.

Comment: @GirkovArpa the `std::path` utilities are the definitely the way to go, they're more convenient and more likely to be cross-platform than manual string manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html) type supports a number of methods to manipulate and destructure paths, so it should be straightforward to append a directory. For example:

```
fn append_dir(p: &Path, d: &str) -> PathBuf {
    let dirs = p.parent().unwrap();
    dirs.join(d).join(p.file_name().unwrap())
}
```

I'm testing it on Linux, so for me the test looks like this, but on Windows you should be able to use `C:\...` just fine:

```
fn main() {
    let p = Path::new(r"/foo/bar.txt");
    assert_eq!(append_dir(&p, "baz"), Path::new(r"/foo/baz/bar.txt"));
}
```